# Google OAuth2 connecting to personal Gmail account "This app is blocked" error

Tags: google-oauth

Our app has the SMTP feature that allows the user to connect Gmail with OAuth2, this works fine if the account is Google Workspace type, but if we try to connect to a personal Gmail account, the OAuth2 shows the "This app is blocked" error as below image.

Any thought?

NOTE: Our code works fine if connecting Google Workspace account, just has this issue if trying to connect personal Google Gmail account.

[image]

Comment: Have you submitted your application for Google verification? https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865#:~:text=app%20to%20complete.-,Unverified%20app%20user%20cap,-To%20protect%20users

Comment: Yeah, our application was verified, our code works fine if connecting Google Workspace account, just has this issue if trying to connect personal Google Gmail account.

Comment: Did you make any changes related to the scopes you are requesting?

Comment: No - The scopes are the same, tried below two versions and all didn't work.   
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`

OR   
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://mail.google.com/`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you didn't activate the [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=it) in your Google Settings!

Simply, go to your Google profile settings, search for "less secure" into the searchbar and you will be prompted to a checkbox. Keep in mind that it will be automatically turned off in 30 days.

To avoid this, you should add a proper authentication to your app.

Comment: thanks, the "Less secure app access" setting is no longer available now, also a reminder, we are using OAuth2 to connect personal Gmail account, not use basic auth(username/password), any idea? or something I misunderstood.

Comment: so sad they brang it down. by the way, if i remember right, you can use the token.pickle. paired with oauth2, it should enable the login